# Why does adding "& 1" to an assign statement produce a completely different synthesis?

Tags: verilog, adder, hdl

I am trying to implement a one-bit full adder in Verilog. Here's my original code:

```
module add1 ( input a, input b, input cin,   output sum, output cout );

       assign sum = (a + b + cin) & 1;
       assign cout = ((a + b + cin) >> 1); // no "& 1" at the end

endmodule
```

This produces the following synthesis:
[image]

As apparent from the image, `cout` is directly connected to 0. However, adding an "& 1" at the end of the assign statement:

```
   assign cout = ((a + b + cin) >> 1) & 1;
```

produces the correct synthesis.

I am very new to Verilog so I am wondering what's going on.

Comment: Hello Syed. It's been a while since I used Verilog, but why are you performing a bitwise AND on the equation for `sum` and why are you performing a register shift on the equation for `cout`? Shouldn't you have a single line of body code, `assign {cout, sum} = (a + b + cin);`? My guess is that you need the second `&1` because you did it to the first line even though you didn't need it or the second line. I could be wrong, though. It's been a while.

Comment: Oh, didn’t think of that one. Thank you for pointing that out. As mentioned in the accepted answer, it seems like the single-line code would be correct and elegant.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which tool are you using for synthesis? Nice netlist graphic in there

Comment: Thanks! It's Yosys (forgot version number) that I ran from edaplayground.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unique thing about Verilog compared to other programming languages is the concept of operand width and the context of operands and operators with different widths. The widths of certain operands get extended *before* applying the operators.

When you have a simple expression

```
L >> R
```

The width of result that expression is just the width of `L`. The width of `R` has no part in the width of the result and is not part of the expression context. If `L` is the expression `a+b+cin`, and all those signals are single bits, the the result of that operations in a single bit. Shifting a single bit right by any number of places results in single bit 0 value.

When you append `& 1` to the expression, that is the same as appending `& 32'sd1` which is a 32-bit signed decimal 1. Verilog will extend all operands in the context of the expression to 32-bits; so now the result of the addition is also 32-bits. The following would also give you the correct result:

```
assign cout = ((a + b + cin) >> 1) & 1;
assign cout = ((a + b + cin) >> 1) + 0;
assign cout = ((a + b + cin) >> 1) + 2'b00;
assign cout = ((a + b + cin + 0) >> 1);
```

But a better way of writing this is

```
assign {cout, sum} = a + b + cin;
```

Section *11.6.1 Rules for expression bit lengths* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595) explains this in more detail for all operators.